# Team Froundation Service fails to build VSPackage (VsSDK not found)

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-sdk, resharper-sdk

I'm trying to use the [MS Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) to build our VisualStudio Extensions. Unfortunately, the build server fails to build my solution, issuing the error message

> <my-project>.csproj: The imported project "$(MSBuildExtensionPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets" was not found.

I take from [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600723/tfs-2010-build-do-i-need-to-install-visual-studio-2010-on-tfs-2010-build-serve) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239418/the-imported-project-microsoft-webapplications-targets-was-not-found) that this means the SDK extension is not installed on the machine running our build. I am aware that I can probably include the whole SDK in my solution and set the import paths accordingly, but that does not seem a proper solution to me... especially, because the same problem arises with the ReSharper SDK and potentially others in the future.

Hence, the question is: *Is it possible to build projects relying on the VsSDK (or other build extensions) through the Team Foundation Service?*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an always up-to-date list of what's installed on the hosted build servers for Team Foundation Service:  http://listofsoftwareontfshostedbuildserver.azurewebsites.net/.  The Visual Studio SDK doesn't appear to be installed after quickly skimming the list.

Another option for you is to setup your own build server(s), either on-premises or in Windows Azure and connect it to Team Foundation Service.  You can then install whatever you need on your custom build servers.

Comment: I guess setting up our own build machine is the best solution. Its still less work than setting up our own TFS and is reusable in case we decide to move away from TFService in the future. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @salsolatragus no problem at all.  If you want to get really fancy, you can create your own build server VM template and upload it as your own VHD into Azure Storage.  You can then create as many build servers as you need at any given time to create a build farm.

Comment: I think that's overdoing it for us, but nice to know anyways ;)